# Code prints out correctly with a leading space.

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming and I'm having probably a simple issue.
I've looked all over the site looking for an answer to this but my no luck. 
So my program runs fine if at the end of the input file there is a space. For example running the program from command line in unix

./program-name < file.txt

if the file.txt is 
//with a space whith | | being a space. 
The Cat Ran.| |
I get the correct output 1 1 1

if it is 
The Cat Ran.(With no space I get 1 1)

```
//I have to use C for this program.
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int i=0;
    char c;
    int NOV=0;

        while( (c=getchar())!=EOF && c !='\n' && c !=10 ){

        if( c=='a'||c=='e'||c=='i'||c=='o'||c=='u' ){
            NOV++;
        }
        if(c==' '){
            printf("%d ",NOV);
            NOV=0;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: The program shown seems to output the value of `NOV` on every space read from the file. `NOV` seems to count the number of vowels in each started word. What is the expected output? If you would like to have the number of wovels counted in the last word too without terminating it with a space, you would have to execute the statement for the `(c==' ')` in addition after the loop or use a different loop.

Comment: Formatting your code correctly is a great help for finding errors.

Comment: @codor: 'wovels'?  Novel (or do I mean Vonel?).

Comment: I missspelled it, I mean 'vowels' indeed.

Comment: It seems you want to print the number of vowels in a word. The problem is the word separator. Only whitespace is considered as word separator in this code, but what if comma, period, exclamation or even EOF itself? Try fixing this!

Comment: @HerringtonDarkholme: except that `key:value` would be considered one word and not two (and you can argue either way on that; it also means that `Mary O'Hara` is correctly counted as just two words, not as three), there isn't a major problem with punctuation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble is that when you get EOF without a space, you exit the loop, and nothing after the loop prints the number of vowels.

Add `if (NOV != 0) printf("%d", NOV);` after the loop, perhaps.

Separately, your use of 10 is odd; '\n' is control-J or 10.  You might be thinking of control-M, aka carriage return or `'\r'`.

Also, as Blue Pixy pointed out in a comment, you should always use `int c;` to receive the return from `getchar()` or `getc()` of `fgetc()`.  The functions return an `int`, which may be any value that fits in an `unsigned char` or EOF, a negative value.  You run into problems if you use `char c` instead.

Comment: Thanks that made sense. I was using 10 because the teacher said that was for end of line seemed strange to me also.

Answer (score 0):

Your program should read like this (a lot of useless clutter has been removed) :

```
int main(void) 
{
  int c;
  int nov = 0;

  while( (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
  {
    if( c=='a'||c=='e'||c=='i'||c=='o'||c=='u' )
      nov++;
   }

  printf("%d\n", nov)  ;

  return 0;
}
```